# USB Headset disables my mouse on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, hid, usb-headset

I have a strange issue: I cannot use my mouse and my headset at once.

```
Linux sheep 3.12.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 4 21:45:42 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1.)

I plug in my Logitech Mouseman Cordless Optical Human Interface Device (Mouse) into USB.

```
[  970.634416] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  970.877377] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[  970.899806] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  970.899809] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  970.908255] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input14
[  970.908462] hid-generic 0003:046D:C508.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0
```

Works perfectly!

2.)

I plug in my Blaupunkt CW-112 Headset and power-on the sender (at the USB port)

```
[ 1076.841418] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1077.080957] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

3.)

HID isn't working any more. No mouse movements on screen. Touchpad of laptop still works.

Re-attaching the mouse has no effect. It still doesn't work. Though:

```
[0] % lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c508 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Trackball
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1008  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does anybody know how to fix such an issue?

Best,
mc

Comment: After plugging in the headset, what happens if you plug in another USB device, like a drive?  Does it work?  It could be to much power is being drawn.

Comment: A USB stick works perfectly. Even when the headset is deactivated, after being plugged in only once, I cannot get the mouse to work. The headset persistently deactivates my USB HID support as it seems. Until I reboot.

Comment: a usb flash drive ('stick') doesn't consume as much power as a spinning drive. you might try not to use any front usb ports (on a tower)

Comment: the point is that the deactivation remains. even when the headset, once initiated, gets unplugged.